# Apache Jena Commands not found

Tags: jena

I'm trying to set up my system (Ubuntu 16.04) with Apache Jena 3.10.0, and followed the provided instructions, but I'm unable to access any of the commands that I should have access to.

For example, `sparql --version` and `bin/sparql --version` both return:

`sparql: command not found`

I have downloaded and extracted the files to `/home/[user]/apache-jena-3.10.0`, then run:

```
export JENA_HOME=/home/[user]/apache-jena-3.10.0  
export PATH=$PATH:$JENA_HOME/bin
```

The command `cd $JENA_HOME` successfully goes the `apache-jena-3.10.0` directory.

I feel that there is a basic linux thing here that I'm missing, but I've tried a lot of things and had no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying this in the same terminal window that you ran the two `export` commands given?  Changes to your environment won't persist across different terminal windows/login sessions.  If you want that to happen you would need to add those statements to your profile file (which will vary depending on your Shell).  Output of `echo $PATH` and `which sparql` would also be useful extra information on your question

Comment: Thanks for your response. `which sparql` gave no output, which led me in the right direction to make the file executable with `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

The files in the download from Apache were not marked as executable. From the main `apache-jena-3.10.0` directory, `chmod -R 775 bin` changed all files so I could run them from command line.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird.  Just downloaded the Apache Jena distribution and the files in `bin/` all appear executable.  Where exactly did you download it from?

Comment: I downloaded it from the main page: [https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi](https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi)